# CSS IE issue with having two divs in one line

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have got the following code working fine on FF. As you can guess, I want the following two divs stays on one line without breaking when browser resize.

```
<div style="float: left;  margin-right: 10px; ">

</div>

<div style="overflow: hidden;">

</div>
```

But as per usual, when I tested the page with IE 9, the right div was already below the left one.

Can someone pls help me out here, thanks,

Comment: Try floating to right instead. If the upper `div` floats to the right, the lower one comes to the left.

Answer (score 0):

you also `float` the other `div`

```
<div style="float: left;  margin-right: 10px; ">

</div>

<div style="float:right; overflow: hidden;">

</div>
```

==========================================================>>>

**UPDATE**

HTML

```
<div class="marginRight"></div>
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:45%;
    height:100px;
}
.marginRight {margin-right: 10px;}
```

WORKING [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/wLM8U/)

Comment: no man, this does not help me as it puts both divs to the sides, whereas I want the right one to fill the whole right space

Comment: for that problem you can wrap the two `div` with another `div`

Comment: hi can you show image so that i can easily figure out what you want to achieve if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Either add `"float:right`" in your second div or
add `"width:XXpx"` into your first div.

Answer (score 0):

***Wrap it with another div***

```
<div>
   <div style="float: left;  margin-right: 10px; ">

   </div>

   <div style="float:right; overflow: hidden;">

   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is working fine

if you want more configuring

```
<div style="display:table-row;">
 <div style="width:49%; margin-right:2%; height:100px; float:left; display:table-cell;"> any thing you wanted  </div>
 <div style="width:49%; height:100px; float:left; display:table-cell;"> any thing you wanted </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a container div and set the two divs to either % of total width or total px of the page.

```
#containerdiv {
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
#leftdiv {
width:20%;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
#rightdiv {
width:80%;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
}


<div id="containerdiv">
<div id="leftdiv"> TEST </div>
<div id="rightdiv"> TEST </div>
</div>
```

Remember if you use margins and paddings you will need to adjust the percentages or pixels for it to line up next.
For example.  If you add padding 1% to left div, it will push the right div down to second line since you are now at a total of 101% of the container divs width.